# Webmock test for failure to connect fails before finishing test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, webmock

I have test to for connection error:

```
context 'unsuccessful API request' do
  it 'responds like 500 if connection error is raised' do
    http_stub = instance_double(Net::HTTP)
    allow(Net::HTTP).to receive(:new).and_return(http_stub)
    allow(http_stub).to receive(:request).and_raise(Errno::ECONNREFUSED)

    api_client = ApiClient.new

    api_client.create_implementer('Wayfarer')

    expect(api_client.response_status).to eq(500)
    expect(api_client.response_body).to eq({ issue' => [{ 'details' => { 'text' => 'Connection error' }}]})
  end
end
```

And when I run it, it fails like it's supposed to but fails in the method instead of in the test so the test for the failure fails:

```
Failure/Error: response = http.request(request)
     
Errno::ECONNREFUSED:
  Connection refused
```

Which is the correct error but it's failing in the method:

```
  def http_request(request, uri)
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

    response = http.request(request)
    @response_status = response.code.to_i

    if response_successful?
      @response_body = parsed_response(response)
    else
      @response_body = response.body rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
      connection_error
    end
  end
```

The issue is it's stopping in the middle of the `http_request` method at the line for `response = http.request(request)`. It doesn't follow through with the error handling.

If I put a `binding.pry` after that line it isn't reached and the method just bails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [expect the error to be raised](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher) in your spec

```
 expect { api_client.create_implementer('Wayfarer') }.to raise_error(Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

Comment: The issue is it's stopping in the middle of the `http_request` method at the line for `response = http.request(request)`. It doesn't follow through with the error handling.

Comment: It still happens even with the change from my answer?

Comment: It does. I put it after `api_client.create_implementer('Wayfarer')`. Is it supposed to go anywhere else?

Comment: Not after, you need to replace the line api_client.create_implementer('Wayfarer') with expect { api_client.create_implementer('Wayfarer') }.to raise_error(Errno::ECONNREFUSED) . You never catch the exception thrown there, thats why your spec fails

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know how to redirect in a `Errno::ECONNREFUSED:  Connection refused` scenario?